# Authentication implemention problem with Auth0 and Winforms

Tags: winforms, oauth, auth0, restsharp

I wonder if anybody can assist me. I am deeply, deeply frustrated by trying to implement what I understand should be a fairly straightforward authentication implementation.

My objective is to have users login in to a .NET 6 Winforms client application. Auth0 is the IDP for the login. Once logged in, the Winforms client application code should use the issued access token to call a ASP .NET Core MVC-style Web API.

The client login part seems to work OK, at least superficially. I have this code in the client which does the login:

```
private async void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Auth0ClientOptions clientOptions = new Auth0ClientOptions
    {
        Domain = this.config["Auth0Domain"].ToString(),
        ClientId = this.config["Auth0ClientId"].ToString(),
        Scope = "offline_access"
    };
    
    var client = new Auth0Client(clientOptions);
    clientOptions.PostLogoutRedirectUri = clientOptions.RedirectUri;
   
    var loginResult = await client.LoginAsync();

    if (loginResult != null)
    {
        if (loginResult.IsError)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(loginResult.Error, "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            this.accessTokenLifetimeManager = new AccessTokenLifetimeManager
                (loginResult, 300, cancellationOnExitTokenSource.Token, config);

            var refreshTokenTask = Task.Run(accessTokenLifetimeManager.PeriodicallyRefreshAccessTokensWorkerTaskAsync);

            vr2Button.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Once user has successfully logged in, I have an access token in the loginResult object. (Incidentally, I have copied this token from my IDE and put it into jwt.io, and jwt.io says "Invalid Signature", but shows a valid Header and empty payload. I am not sure why I would have received an access token in response to a successful login which is not JWT compliant, so I assume that there is some highly-technical reason for this which is beyond my understanding. I'm not countenancing that Auth0 will be issuing invalid tokens...maybe they are just signed differently to what jwt.io expects?).

Anyway, what I'm trying to do next is to take that Access token, and use it to call my API, also secured by Auth0.  This is the Program.cs code for my API:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var GoogleTextSpeechApiKey = builder.Configuration["GoogleTextSpeech:apikey"];


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = $"https://{builder.Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/";
    options.Audience = builder.Configuration["Auth0:Audience"];
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier
    };
    
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

My API controller looks like this (some code left out for readability):

```
    [Authorize]
    public class ModelResourceController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

        public ModelResourceController(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("ModelResource/Model/{id}")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ModelAsync(string id)
        {
        //...
        }
    }
```

Back in my winforms client, I am using this code to call my API; this uses RestSharp as the http client.

```
    public static partial class GetDiscreteResourceTasks
    {
        private static readonly string restClientBaseUrl;

        private static readonly RestClient restClient;

        private static readonly TimeSpan maxDelay;

        private static readonly IEnumerable<TimeSpan> delay;

        private static AsyncRetryPolicy<RestResponse> resourcesRetryPolicy;

        private static AsyncRetryPolicy<RestResponse<ScoreValues>> calculateScoresRetryPolicy;

        static GetDiscreteResourceTasks()
        {
#if LOCAL
                restClientBaseUrl = @"https://localhost:7230";
#else
                restClientBaseUrl = @"xxx";
#endif

            restClient = new RestClient(restClientBaseUrl);
//...
        }

        public static async Task<RestResponse> GetJsonModelAsync(AccessTokenLifetimeManager.TokenValuesClass tokenValues, string resourceId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            string htmlResourceId = @"ModelResource/Model/" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceId);

#if DEBUG

                var request = new RestRequest(htmlResourceId, Method.Get);

        //tokenValues.AccessToken.ToJwtBearerHeaderValue() is equivalent to "Bearer <AccessToken>"
                request.AddOrUpdateHeader("Authorization", tokenValues.AccessToken.ToJwtBearerHeaderValue());

                var response = await restClient.ExecuteAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            return response;


#else
//...
#endif
        }

//...
    }
}
```

My RestSharp client returns "Request failed with status code Unauthorized"
Status Code: Unauthorized
The WWW-Authenticate header value is Bearer error="invalid_token"

In the Auth0 GUI, there is NO log activity for the API, only for the Client. It seems that the API is not reaching out to Auth0 for authentication at all, which makes me suspect that the ASP .NET Core  runtime is rejecting the token on some kind of short-circuit basis, but I cannot understand why that would be the case, given that this Access token is issued by Auth0 in response to a successful client login.

I would be grateful for any advice as to either what I'm doing wrong, or how I continue to troubleshoot this issue further. I am completely at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify an audience with your login / refresh request.

```
    var client = new Auth0Client(clientOptions);
    clientOptions.PostLogoutRedirectUri = clientOptions.RedirectUri;

    var extraLoginParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    extraLoginParams.Add("audience", "<your api audience>");
               
    var loginResult = await client.LoginAsync(extraParameters: extraLoginParams);
```